# how to get the resultset from users-by-username-query in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I use Spring login system using the following 2 queries:

1)

```
 users-by-username-query="select email,password,abilitato from
 utente_autenticazione where email=?"
```

2)

```
 authorities-by-username-query="select u1.email, u2.ruolo from 
 utente_autenticazione u1, utente_autorizzazione u2 where
 u1.id_utente = u2.id_utente and u1.email =?
```

Is there a way to handle those resulsets inside a class? I want to be able to know email, password etc, after a user has logged in.

Comment: Why on earth would you need the result set from that. Those are stored in the `UserDetails` object which you can obtain quite easily from the `SecurityContext`. Also the password should be encrypted, if they are not I will not use your program :).

Comment: Actually I dont need the password, I meant I want all the fields from the query, except the password

Comment: Create your own `UserDetails`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom filters for this as below:

**1) Spring-security.xml**

```
 <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
      <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService" >
            <password-encoder hash="bcrypt"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
<beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="successHandler" class="com.demo.service.impl.LoginSuccessHandler" >
        <beans:property name="defaultSuccessUrl" value="user"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="failureHandler" class="com.demo.service.impl.LoginFailureHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="failure"/>
    </beans:bean>

<http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">

      <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="authenticationFilter" />
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/denied"/>
        <logout invalidate-session="true" 
            logout-success-url="/logout/success" 
            logout-url="/logout"/>
      <logout logout-success-url="/login?error"/>
    </http>

<beans:bean id="authenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check"/>
        <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandler"/>
        <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

By doing this after successful login you can access username, password from LoginSuccessHandler.

**2) LoginSuccessHandler**

```
public class LoginSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler{
    private String defaultSuccessUrl;
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication auth) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        String username = auth.getName();
        System.out.println("username>>"+username);
        response.sendRedirect(defaultSuccessUrl);
    }
}
```

In the same way you can also call the LoginFailureHandler to do some work like block the user on number of invalids trials for login.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you man. Actually I already have my own class that extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler and I already know the authentication.getName() method. What I'd like to know is if there's a way to get all the fields from the query, that in my case are "email","password" and "abilitato". From Authentication I'm not able to know the value of the field "abilitato" or the other fields that I'd like to add to my "users-by-username-query".

Comment: I can't understand what you exactly want. you can get the same value after user login based on the username.may be in LoginSuccessHandler or somewhere else whereever you want

Comment: I should write another query and get all the user values using  "where username =...". Of course I can do it, I was asking if i can avoid writing another query. I was wondering if existed something like "Authentication.users-by-username-queryGetQueryFields()"